# Importing blender JSON in Three.js

Tags: javascript, json, three.js, blender

Hi I am having problems importing models from blender in three.js.

At this moment I am using the last version of three.js (R71). I installed the exporter of three.js in blender and exports fine.

This is the code of HTML.

```
<body>
    <font size="+6"><b>TFG</b></font><br>
    <a href="../index.html">Volver a atrás</a>
    <hr>
    <div id='container'></div>      
    <script src="libs/ThreeJSV71/build/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/OrbitControls.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/Coordinates.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/dat.gui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/stats.min.js"></script>   
    <script src="libs/ColladaLoader.js"></script>   

    <script src="threejs/tfg2.js"></script>
    <br>
</body>
```

The next file is the tfg2.js where I load the model.

```
var width = window.innerWitdh,
    height = window.innerHeight,
    clock = new THREE.Clock(),
    scene,
    camera,
    renderer,
    ambientLight,
    directionalLight,
    loader,
    modelo = new THREE.Object3D();

init();
function init()
{
    scene =new THREE.Scene();

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(40, width/height, 1000);
    camera.position.set(0,1,5);

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
    renderer.setSize(width,height); 
    renderer.setClearColor(new THREE.Color(0x0000AA));
    document.getElementById('container').appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff);
    scene.add(ambientLight);

    directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
    directionalLight.position.set(0,1,0);
    scene.add(directionalLight);

    scene.add(new THREE.GridHelper(10,1));
    loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
    loader.load('blender/json/camara.json', function(geometry,materials)
    {
        modelo = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials));
        scene.add(modelo);
    });
}
```

When I try to see the results, nothing appear in the webpage and also de JavaScript console don't show any error. If I export the model with collada format and another .js that I have, I can see the model but I need use JSON.

What I am doing wrong?**EDIT:**

Added: modelo.position.set(0,0,0) inside the callback to be sure that the model is in origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are no error what you can do:

1. While exporting the object from blender translate the object to origin. Go to origin>> select origin to geometry>> translate object to x, y, z to zero.
   Now your camera see @ position 0,1,5 xyz respectivily
   Probably where your object camera is not looking
2. Or translate the child of scene to origin

Probably this solve your issue. As I see there are no error and warning in log.

Comment: sorry, i tried it but don't change anything. If it help, the web page have a blue background. When i load another script that don't use any json model but it draws a square, the background turns black. When i use the script that load the json model, the background still blue. maybe it can help to find the problem

Comment: Blue background is because we have renderer clear color blue:
renderer.setClearColor(new THREE.Color(0x0000AA));
black when no json because either object is too big and we are not looking from outside try with scaling of the object.Jsfiddle or zip the share or else you can see you object in the scene children try to debug there.

Comment: Well, this is weird. Your solution helped me but it was not the problem. The problem is the camera. I Changed the camera to `camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, aspectRatio,0.1,100);` and also add `camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0));` to be sure that camera is looking origin. Now works fine but keep doing something strange that only loads the JSON model when I pres F12 to open de javascript console. Well, that another problem. Thank you soo much for your help ^^